# how to use property file using jdbc template

Tags: java, sql, spring-mvc, dao, jdbctemplate

// I m using  template.setFetchSize(100); again n again every daoImpl. how to use this in property file and use

```
    JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    String sql = "";

    // process 100 rows at a time to minimize memory consumption
    template.setFetchSize(100);

    template.query(sql, new RowCallbackHandler() {
    public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the DRY principle:

Given a `myjdbc.properties`

```
fetchSize = 100
```

use either a class

```
public class StandardJdbcTemplate extends JdbcTemplate {
    private static final int FETCH_SIZE =
            ResourceBundler.get("myjdbc").getInt("fetchSize");
    public StandardJdbTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource);
        setFetchSize(FETCH_SIZE);
    }
}

JdbcTemplate template = new StandardJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
```

Alternatively you could use a *factory* class to yield a JdbcTemplate.

```
public static JdbTemplate createJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) { ... }
```

Comment: Maybe you thought of having some global class with a `public static final int FETCH_SIZE`. Personally I dislike classes passing out constants, hence my encorporating them at the using class. Even less nice, would be read the ResourceBundle at every JdbcTemplate.